# Programmatically performing gradient calculation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, linear-algebra, backpropagation, calculus

Let y = Relu(Wx) where W is a 2d matrix representing a linear transformation on x, a vector. Likewise, let m = Zy, where Z is a 2d matrix representing a linear transformation on y. How do I programmatically calculate the gradient of Loss = sum(m^2) with respect to W, where the power means take the element wise power of the resulting vector, and sum means adding all the elements together?

I can work this out slowly mathematically by taking a hypothetical, multiplying it all out, then element-by-element taking the derivative to construct the gradient, but I can't figure out an efficient approach to write a program once the neural network layer becomes >1.

Say, for just one layer (m = Zy, take gradient wrt Z) I could just say

```
Loss = sum(m^2)
dLoss/dZ  = 2m * y
```

where * is the outer product of the vectors, and I guess this is kind of like normal calculus and it works. Now for 2 layers + activation (gradient wrt W), if I try to do it like "normal" calculus and apply the chain rule I get:

```
dLoss/dW = 2m * Z * dRelu * x
```

where dRelu is the derivative of Relu(Wx) except here I have no idea what * means in this case to make it work.

Is there an easy way to calculate this gradient mathematically without basically multiplying it all out and deriving each separate element in the gradient? I'm really unfamiliar with matrix calculus, so if anyone could also give some mathematical intuition, if my attempt is completely wrong, that would be appreciated.

Comment: So you specifically want it done manually rather than use an automatic differentiation library?

Comment: I would recommend to follow a complete tutorial with demonstrations and assignments in order to fully comprehend the subject. Linear Algebra is mandatory in deep learning. See [Stanfor's tutorial and unsupervised feature learning](http://deeplearning.stanford.edu/tutorial/)

Comment: @mr_mo If you have any idea of resources for learning how to do this kind of matrix calculus I would appreciate it. I've studied linear algebra, the problem is I can't find good resources to teach me how to do matrix calculus.

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos - Yeah, I want to understand how this is mathematically done, though it would be very straightforward with a library.

Comment: @Matt  probably [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus)

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of convenience, let's ignore the ReLU for a moment. You have an input space X (of some size [dimX]) mapped to an intermediate space Y (of some size [dimY]) mapped to an output space m (of some size [dimM]) You have, then, W: X → Y a matrix of shape [dimY, dimX] and Z: Y → m a matrix of shape [dimM, dimY]. Finally your loss is simply a function that maps your M space to a scalar value.

Let us walk the way backwards. As you correctly said, you want to compute the derivative of the loss w.r.t W and to do so you need to apply the chain rule all the way back. You then have:

dL/dW = dL/dm * dm/dY * dY/dW

- dL/dm is of shape [dimm] (a scalar function with derivatives across dimm dimensions)
- dm/dY is of shape [dimm, dimY] (an m-dimensional function with derivatives across dimY dimensions)
- dY/dW is of shape [dimY, dimW] = [dimY, dimY, dimX] (a y-dimensional function with derivatives across [dimY, dimX] dimensions)

**Edit**:

- To make the last bit more clear, Y consists of dimY different values, so Y can  be treated as dimY constituent functions. We need to apply the gradient operator on each of those mini-functions, all with respect to the basis vectors defined by W. More concretely, if W = [[w11, w12], [w21, w22], [w31, w32]] and x = [x1, x2], then Y = [y1, y2, y3] = [w11x1 + w12x2, w21x1 + w22x2, w31x1 + w32x2]. Then W defines a 6d space (3x2) across which we need to differentiate. We have dY/dW = [dy1/dW, dy2/dW, dy3/dW], and also dy1/dW = [[dy1/dw11, dy1/dw12], [dy1/dw21, dy1/dw22], [dy1/dw31, dy1/dw32]] = [[x1,x2],[0,0],[0,0]], a 3x2 matrix. So dY/dW is a [3,3,2] tensor.
- As for the multiplication part; the operation here is tensor contraction (essentially matrix multiplication in high dimension spaces). Practically, if you have a high-order tensor A[[a1, a2, a3... ], β] (i.e. a+1 dimensions, the last of which is of size β) and a tensor B[β, [b1, b2...]] (i.e. b+1 dimensions, the first of which is β), their tensor contraction is a matrix C[[a1,a2...], [b1,b2...]] (i.e. a+b dimensions, the β dimension contracted), where C is obtained by summing over element-wise across the shared dimension β (refer to https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html#numpy.tensordot).

The resulting tensor contraction then is a matrix of shape [dimY, dimX] which can be used to update your W weights. The ReLU which we ignored earlier can easily be thrown in the mix, since ReLU: 1 → 1 is a scalar function applied element-wise on Y.

To summarize, your code would be:

```python
W_gradient = 2m * np.dot(Z, x) * np.e**x/(1+np.e**x))
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm not following a couple of ideas here. First, what do the "*" here mean if they are different dimension matrices? Second, if Y = Wx, I don't understand what you mean when you say dY/dW then becomes the 3D matrix [dimY, dimY, dimX] - how did you calculate that? If it's not too difficult could you work through this with the variables I gave so I have a better idea of how to computationally structure it?

Comment: Changed original answer. If you still have trouble, feel free to ask. Try to write the equations down on paper and justify the use of dot over tensordot in the codeblock.

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented several multiplier neural networks(MLP) from scratch in C++[1], and I think I know what's your pain. And believe me, you don't even need any third party matrix/tensor/automatic differentiation(AD) libraries to do the matrix multiplication or gradient calculation. There are three things you should pay attention to:

- There are two kinds of multiplication in the equations: matrix multiplication, and elementwise multiplication, you'll mess up if you denoted them all as a single `*`.
- Use concrete examples, especially concrete numbers as dimensions of your data/matrix/vector to build intuition.
- The most powerful tool for programming correctly is `dimension compatibility`, always don't forget to check dimensions.

Suppose your want to do binary classification and the neural network is `input -> h1 -> sigmoid -> h2 -> sigmoid -> loss` in which input layer has 1 sample each has 2 features, h1 has 7 neurons, and h2 has 2 neurons. Then:

forward pass:

```
Z1(1, 7) = X(1, 2) * W1(2, 7)
A1(1, 7) = sigmoid(Z1(1, 7))
Z2(1, 2) = A1(1, 7) * W2(7, 2)
A2(1, 2) = sigmoid(Z2(1, 2))
Loss = 1/2(A2 - label)^2
```

backward pass:

```
dA2(1, 2) = dL/dA2 = A2 - label
dZ2(1, 2) = dL/dZ2 = dA2 * dsigmoid(A2_i) -- element wise
dW2(7, 2) = A1(1, 7).T * dZ2(1, 2)        -- matrix multiplication
```

Notice the last equation, the dimension of the gradient of `W2` should match `W2`, which is `(7, 2)`. And the only way to get a `(7, 2)` matrix is to transpose input `A1` and multiply `A1` with `dZ2`, that's dimension compatibility[2].

backward pass continued:

```
dA1(1, 7) = dZ2(1, 2) * A1(2, 7)        -- matrix multiplication
dZ1(1, 7) = dA1(1, 7) * dsigmoid(A1_i)  -- element wise
dW1(2, 7) = X.T(2, 1) * dZ1(1, 7)       -- matrix multiplication
```

[1] The code is [here](https://github.com/elinx/mlp), you can see the hidden layer implementation, naive matrix implementation and the references listed there.

[2] I omit the matrix derivation part, it's simple actually but hard to type the equations out. I strongly suggest you read [this paper](http://vision.stanford.edu/teaching/cs231n/handouts/derivatives.pdf), every tiny detail you should know on matrix derivation in DL is listed in this paper.

[3] One sample as input is used in the above example(as a vector), you can substitute 1 with any batch numbers(become matrix), and the equations still hold.